# Listing database tables for sqlite in R

Tags: r, sqlite, dplyr, r-package, rsqlite

I am unable to list tables for the sqlite database I am connecting to from R.

I setup the tables in my database (WBS_test1.db) using "DB Browser" https://sqlitebrowser.org/

Looking at this db in the command window, I am able to list the tables via .tables and view the data headers via .schema so I know they are (can also preview in DB Browser of course).

In R however...,
I set my working directory, etc.

```
library(DBI)
library(RSQLite)
setwd(dir = "C:/here/there/folder")
sqlite <- dbDriver("SQLite")
```

I then connect to the database and attempt to list the tables and fields in one of the tables specifically

```
DBtest <- dbConnect(sqlite,"WBS_Test1.db")
dbListTables(DBtest)
dbListFields(DBtest, "WBS_CO2")
```

I get a "character(0)" returned, which from searching around looks like it's saying the tables are temporary.

I've also tried using the dplyr package

```
library(dplyr)

# connect to the sqlite file
test_db <- src_sqlite("C:/SQLite/WBS_test.db", create = TRUE)
src_tbls(test_db)
```

This again returns a "character(0)"

I have no prior experience with SQLite and modest experience in R so I'm probably missing something simple but I can't figure it out. Suggestions??? Maybe I'm not directing my wd in the correct location for the RSQLite package?

Thanks!

Comment: FYI: you can remove `library(RSQLite)` and use of `dbDriver` if you do `cbDonnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ...)`. No difference in performance, intent, safety, etc, just reduced code.

Comment: You are using the `DBI` and `dplyr` functions correctly, so your database is suspect. How confident are you that the sqlite file contains tables and your data? For instance, I did `con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "foo.sqlite")`, `dbWriteTable(con, "mt", mtcars)`, and `dbListTables(con)` (returned `[1] "mt"`) without issue, effectively what you are doing above.

Comment: I tested your code and it is working correctly. Something wrong with your `.db`.
`closeAllConnections()`  
`rm(list=ls())`  
`ls()`  
`library(DBI)`  
`con <- dbDriver("SQLite")`  
`DBtest <- dbConnect(con,"survey.db")`  
`dbListTables(DBtest)`  
`[1] "Person"  "Site"    "Survey"  "Visited"`  
`dbListFields(DBtest, "Site")`  
`[1] "name" "lat"  "long"`

Comment: Check the database without R.  In shell or cmd go to the directory containng the SQLite database and then run `sqlite3 WBS_test.db` (assuming you have installed the sqlite3 command line program) and then when you get the sqlite prompt try `select * from sqlite_master;` .

Comment: @r2evans et al., thanks for double checking my R code. Glad to see I mostly have that correct. It does appear my .db is the issue but I still can's see where (see response to G. Grothendieck)

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I had checked in cmd but double checked doing exactly what you said and I get 5 tables with headers listed, don't see an issue there. Could admin-privileges be interfering? Or again, am is the wd defaulting to somewhere else?

Comment: SQLite doesn't require or even benefit from admin privileges (except for whether you have write-access to the directory, which is fs-based, not db-based). Does the file look like it contains data? That is, is the file size representative of the data volume and does it increase while building it?

Comment: @r2evans yep, .db is about 37MB. Here is the code for one of my tables: 
   CREATE TABLE `WBS_CO2` (
 `Recod_No` NUMERIC,
 `Year` NUMERIC,
 `Jday` NUMERIC,
 `Hour` NUMERIC,
 `Minute` NUMERIC,
 `Datetime` TEXT,
 `Site_ID` TEXT,
 `cfx006s` NUMERIC,
 `cfx006i` NUMERIC,
 `cfx026s` NUMERIC,
 `cfx026i` NUMERIC,
 `cfx041s` NUMERIC,
 `cfx044i` NUMERIC,
 `cfx063s` NUMERIC,
 `cfx063i` NUMERIC,
 PRIMARY KEY(`Recod_No`)
    );

Comment: I think SQLite deals with multi-access just fine, but do you have anything else using the database that might be locking it? You can try a "clean" test by rebooting or copying the db to another computer and trying it in R there. (I know nothing about the app you're using, perhaps it is locking the file?)